# aligning ul li elements

Tags: html, css, list, vertical-alignment

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPkyQ/1/)

I have a list of items where each `<li>` contains an image that should be on the left and a descriptor that should be on the right. These two elements should align along their top axis.
For some reason, the first descriptor is aligned with the second image, the second descriptor with the third image, etc. I'm not at all sure what's going on. Any ideas?

I've created a JSFiddle (above) and an image of what I'm going for (below).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, this should set you on the right path:

http://jsfiddle.net/aPkyQ/7/